# $.getJSON not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a very simple chrome extension for my school. I am fairly certain the underlying issue is that chrome doesn't allow XHR requests by default, but at the same time, was expecing the #results div ([here is the code](http://jsbin.com/egudo4/2/edit)) to populate. I've read about certain things like jSONP, but then again, I'm not quite sure what's causing this. I'd appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in thinking this was a cross-site issue. If you look at the Chrome console, you should see something like:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://slu.edu/peoplefinder/json/json_index.php?q=.
>   Origin http://jsbin.com is not allowed
>   by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

If you're running this on a server with scripting capabilities (eg: PHP), you can create a script on your own server which will fetch the remote data instead of doing it in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

For chrome extensions to break cross-origin policies, you need to add the domain to your manifest file via the permissions entry:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "http://slu.edu/",
  "http://*.google.com/",
  "unlimitedStorage"
],
```

Source: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions